# require: No such file to load -- test_helper (LoadError) happens only in production not in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am new to Ruby on Rails and following Michael Hartl's Ruby On Rails Tutorial.  I am on Chapter 9 and everything works fine in development - all tests pass and I can open and move around the app.  However, when I try to open in production (Heroku), the application crashes.  Here is the Heroku console error message:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': No such file to load -- test_helper (LoadError)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /app/app/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

I get the same message if I try

```
rails s -e production
```

I have confirmed that my test_helper.rb file is indeed in my test folder.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a stab in the dark, but are you requiring your test_helper somewhere else in your application? From reading the backtrace it looks like you're requiring it in `app/app/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb`.

Also, the `app/app/`looks fishy. Do you have an app folder inside of your app folder? That could be a problem too.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  Actually what happened is I had a copy of sessions_helper_test.rb in the app/helpers folder.  It should not have been in here but rather should have been in the test folder only.  Now, thanks to you, I can make more sense of those long error messages.

Comment: Happy to help! Cheers! :-)